# Typed in wrong repo remote name

Tags: git

[New to git]
In the midst of making my first repo,  I misspelled my username in the directory.
`git remote add origin [website/wrong username/repo name.git]`
I tried doing `git rm origin`, and also deleting the branch, but that didn't work either.

What other things can I do? I've actually tried

Comment: Read the output of `git help remote`

Comment: This is answered directly in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) already.

Answer (score 3):

You can change it with ([`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)):

```
git remote set-url origin ....
```

But if you already '`remote rm`' that remote, then a simple `git remote add` is enough.
[`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm), on the other end, has nothing to do with remote, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124061/typed-in-wrong-repo-remote-name/24124137?noredirect=1#comment37219490_24124137) by [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd).

Deleting a local branch wouldn't have any influence on the remotes (that you can see with `git remote -v`)

Comment: The OP did try `git rm origin`, but that didn't work -- and why should it? That's the command to remove a file from the index. `git remote add` won't work, it should be `git remote set-url` (your original answer).

Comment: @hvd true (I read too quickly the 'rm' part). I have edited the answer accordingly.